# Convert string into xmlnode

Tags: c#, xml, string, type-conversion, xmlnode

I was working on C# windows form and wanted to pass the form input text to other .cs file, is it possible to convert **string** into **XMLNode** ?

like string text = "My Name";

and convert it into XMLNode just to save it in xml file.

Comment: Please elaborate more. For example share an input and the expected result. having `string text = "My Name"` what kind of xml output is expected?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer `XDocument`:

```
var doc = new XDocument();
doc.Add(new XElement("Input", "My Name"));
doc.Save(@"..pathToSave\xml.xml");

//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
//<Input>My Name</Input>
```

Comment: But i'm using XMLDocument to load my xml file. and this XDocument is creating a mess with XMLDocument. looking for the code that explicitly convert any string into XMLNode.